# Storing local storage from game in player rankings table

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have created a game, where a user plays and the score is saved within local storage, however i am unsure how to display the scores of the user(s) in a table on my Rankings page

Player Ranking page

```
<?php
include ('common.php');

//Output Title & Navigation
outputHeader("Bugshot | Player Ranking");  
generateNav('Player Ranking');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="user.js"></script>
  </head>    
    <body>
        <div id="pr-heading">
            <h3 div class="subtitle">Earn yourself a spot on the Bug Shot 
    leaderboard</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="pr-subtitle">
            <h3>Player Ranking leaderboard</h3>
        </div>

        <!--Player rankings table-->
            <div id="prTable"></div>

        <!-- Competition banner -->
            <div id="Competition">
                <h3 div class="subtitle">Enter the Bugshot raffle to win ` 
        `$5,000 !</h3>
                    <h3 div class="button">Enter</h3>
            </div>   

        <!--Other Games banner-->    
            <div id="othergames">
                <h3 div class="subtitle">View other games similar to 
        Bugshot</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="imgs/controller.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="imgs/helicopter.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="imgs/tetris.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>     
      </body>        
</html>
<?php
    generateFooter();
?>
```

Local Storage in JavaScript

```
function updateScore(score){
var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);

usrObj.score = score;

localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);}
```

The variable score is passed through from the game, once the user has played

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll want to dynamically generate the html using the localStorage contents. You can write the javascript manually or use an existing library/tool (e.g., jQuery, React) to inject new elements into the page.

Comment: How would i go about writing the javascript manually, so that the scores are displayed in a table form?